# Retain original value even after modifying

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ag-grid

I'm working on Ag-grid.

`this.rowData` is the original data which I'm loading on the grid for the first time.

I've a `addRow` function which will add 1 row at top of the existing rows which works fine.

Now while `reset` function is called, I need yo update the grid to its original data which is `this.rowData`.

Issue is, When I click on `addRow`, even the `this.rowData` gets updated.

Below is my code:

```
Original Data:
 this._Service.httpPost(Request, Url).subscribe(data => {
        responseJson = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
          this.rowData = responseJson;
          this.gridOptions.api.setRowData(this.rowData); // say 6 rows displyed
});

addRow:
addRow() {
let rowData = this.rowData; // created a local variable
 rowData.unshift(newData);// rowData is now 7
 this.gridOptions.api.setRowData(rowData);// rowData is now 7
console.log(this.rowData) // returns 7, not sure why `this.rowData` gets modified
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let rowData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.rowData));

Just do this rest of the code is perfect.

Comment: Thanks it worked. But what is the difference for both of them `this.rowData` and `let rowData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.rowData));`

Comment: As per my knowledge it remove the references by converting the types of data.